# crontab not launching one script

Tags: cron

I have issue with my crontab - cron is not launching one of my scripts

this is top  part of my crontab (root)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

#---------------------------------------
# Items availability
#---------------------------------------


# Daily offer import + daily sync everything
30 7 * * *      /var/www/import/download_offers.sh > /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log

# Updates availability
# 7:45 mass update happens
*/5 0-6 * * *   /var/www/import/check_availability.sh
0,5,10,15,20,25 7 * * * /var/www/import/check_availability.sh
*/5 8-23 * * * /var/www/import/check_availability.sh

#---------------------------------------
# Sales import + sync
#---------------------------------------

# Import EBAY + WWW sales. Run sales cleaner
*/15 * * * *    /var/www/import/import_all.sh
*/5 * * * *     /var/www/import/import_www.sh
55 13 * * *     /var/www/import/import_all.sh
58 13 * * *     /var/www/import/import_www.sh

... more stuff 7KB total ...
```

it used to work perfect for long time but after last week reboot this line

```
30 7 * * *      /var/www/import/download_offers.sh > /var/log/download_offers_cron.log
```

stopped working. contents of download_offers.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Working..."

echo "Download offers started" > /var/log/import/OFFER_START.log

... some private stuff ; just bunch of wget's and echo's ...
```

file `/var/log/import/OFFER_START.log` is not created

what I have tried so far

- I changed time to 7:30, 8:00 (it used to be 7:45 originaly)
- I added `> /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log` but file hasn't been created
- I browsed root emails, all scripts are launched except that one
- file is +x executable

is there some known bug? is there any other option to debug crontab except mails? why script doesn't launch at all? it used to work fine after last week reboot....

Please help I am losing my mind

**Edit:**

I am using CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

this is /var/log/cron

```
Mar 10 07:30:01 serverpro1 CROND[11291]: (root) CMD (/var/www/import/download_offers.sh > /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log)
```

looks like cron entry is fine but there is no /var/log/download_offers_cron.log file anyway?

Comment: Run the scrip manually and see if there are any errors

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha it works fine

Comment: If you run it manually and it works, but doesn't work in cron, then there probably is an environment variable issue. Cron by default only provides a very minimal shell environment. Pay particular attention to PATH and perhaps LD_LIBRARY_PATH varaiables. Best to manually set all required variables in your script than depend on cron to provide. One way to tell what cron provides is to add a very simple cron entry 1 * * * * env > /tmp/cron.env (make sure you delete this entry after it's run as it will keep running at 1 minute after the hour forever if you don't)

Comment: @CosmoF i dont think thats not a case, my "script" is just bunch of echos and wgets

Comment: NB: your crontab says `SHELL=/bin/bash`, then in your script you use `#!/bin/sh`. Your cron is really running as root so it can write to the directories where your logs go? Can you add a `( date ; set ) >>/tmp/cron.log` as 2nd line to your script?

Comment: @ott I changed it to `#!/bin/bash` also I added `( date ; set) >> /tmp/cron.log` as 2nd line in script after shebang, but no file has been created. I ran script manually, file has been created, script works like many other similar scripts. This is entry from /var/log/cron `Mar 12 07:35:01 serverpro1 CROND[18484]: (root) CMD (/var/www/import/download_offers.sh &> /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log)` but no single file has been created, script doesn't work at all

Comment: every other script works fine, no problem at all http://pastebin.com/ittTk2tu scripts are made of echos and wgets only. same permissions, same user/group. i dont get it

Comment: Could your crontab be damaged by CR-LF line endings instead of LF only? Can you do `export EDITOR=vim ; crontab -e` and then within vim `:set notextmode` followed by `:wq`.

Comment: @ott I did it we will see. I highly doubt about it because script shows up in `/var/log/cron` log

Comment: Can you add a hexdump of the first lines of your crontab? Try `hexdump -C /var/spool/cron/user`, if it's not there check the location with `man 5 crontab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it magically works again

only thing i changed was

```
30 7 * * *      /var/www/import/download_offers.sh > /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log
                                                             ^^ here
```

to

```
30 7 * * *      /var/www/import/download_offers.sh > /var/log/download_offers_cron.log
                                                             ^^ here
```

why it caused error and script didnt work AT ALL? I dont know

and why script stopped works in first place is unsolved mystery

Comment: Because try running `/var/www/import/download_offers.sh > /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log` manually and you'll see it should fail with an error like "bash: /var/logs/download_offers_cron.log: No such file or directory".

Comment: And the reason it fails is because the redirect operation `>` is performed before the command is executed.
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation

Answer (score 0):

Check what your /var/log/syslog file says about cron job. Grep the word "cron" from the logs and check what is the error. Use below command to check the same.

grep -i cron /var/log/syslog

Otherwise everything you mentioned is good.

Comment: i am using centos, I checked /var/log/messages but there is nothing there

Comment: Which version you are using ? 
Cron logs on CentOS 6 are located in /var/log/cron by default.

Comment: I am using CentOS release 6.6 (Final). see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab says to use bash, but when you run you script you actually shell out again to the 'sh' shell, thus you lose all your environment variables. I just had this problem last week. My problem was I had no path variable when the script ran in cron, but the script ran fine when I ran it manually.

You can test this by doing this right at the top of your script, after the #!/bin/sh:

```
echo $PATH
echo $path
sleep 10
```

in your script when it is run by cron. I can't recall which path is used by 'sh' so echo both.

Maybe do not shell out to 'sh' in your script?

Or, for each utility you run, enter in the full path to the utility, each input, and each output file.

So if your script says:

`wget ...`

You would replace it with the full path:

`/usr/bin/wget ...`

or whatever the correct path is.

(I can't add comments yet so I won't be able to reply to comments. Sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a typo mistake.
In the first script you use `/var/log`  but in the new one it's `/var/logs`.   Log is the standard directory but you seems to use log**s**